# Partial sorting: nth elements having preseved order

Tags: c++, nth-element, partial-sort

The task is to partially sort a vector with duplicates s.t. the median (nth-element) is at the position it would be, if the vector were sorted. All smaller elements should be on the left, all larger elements on the right. All elements with value same as median have to be in original order - but only these not the rest of the elements.

How would you solve this?

My initial solution:

1. Use std::nth_element() to find median element
2. traverse vector and sort only the elements with same value as median with respect to their index. How would I do this efficiently?

Comment: What is the problem with your current solution?

Comment: I'm looking for a very efficient solution - especially part 2: sorting only specific values of a vector with respect to their indices.

Comment: How do you define "original order" when the elements have the same value? Isnt any permutation of e.g. `{3 3 3 3}` the "original order"?

Comment: It's a k-dimensional vector `vector<Point<T>>`with `struct Point{
    num_t  x,y,z, ID; };` so there is an original order.

Answer (score 0):

Use partition or stable_partition (to preserve original order).

```
class Predicate{
    int median_value;
    public:
    Predicate(int med) : median_value(med) {}
    bool operator()(int x){
    return x < median_value;
    }
};

int main(){

vector<int> v{ 10, 20, 30, 10, 30};

int median = 20;

cout << "median  = " << median << endl;

stable_partition(v.begin(), v.end(), Predicate(median));

for ( auto i : v)
    cout << i << " ";
}
```

Comment: This might work - stable_partition is average O(n) i believe and worst O(nlogn). I'd be interrested though: how would you find the median? With this option, you're not allowed to change the order while finding the median..right?

Comment: didn't address median computation in above code.
probably there is(?) an integrated algorithm to find the median while preserving the order.